# How to segment a region in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to segment a region from an image in MATLAB and display it in a different image file.

[image]

I have tried segmenting it but failed. I want to segment the region from 200:400(i.e. only the regions those are yellow and green)

```
I = imread('Intensity1.jpg');
    imshow(I)
    hold on

    mask = false(size(I));
    mask(200:400) = true;
visboundaries(mask,'Color','b');
```

Comment: What does "the region from 200:400" mean? Rows 200-400? Columns? Both? Color indices? Why would these regions be yellow and green? When you say your attempt failed, what did it do? What did you expect it to do? What is your input image?

Comment: I am unable to upload the image here. is there any attachment link where I can upload it? Then that would explain the problem better.

Comment: You should be able to upload the image and SO will post the link only until you've got enough rep. If not, you can upload the image to imgur.com and post the link here manually.

Comment: <blockquote class="imgur-embed-pub" lang="en" data-id="a/7FmN629"><a href="//imgur.com/a/7FmN629"></a></blockquote><script async src="//s.imgur.com/min/embed.js" charset="utf-8"></script>